# How to change only the subject(CN) in existing csr

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, mdm, client-certificates

I have a csr(Certificate Signing Request).

I have to just change the CN from that csr, leaving other fields intact. It is like updating the existing csr.

This should be done automatically. 
Is there any method to do this in c/c++/openssl?

Comment: DNS names should *not* be placed in the CN. Rather, they are placed in the SAN.

Answer (score 10):

You cannot change anything in the request file, because it is a digitally signed message. If you change at least one bit there, you invalidate the signature. CA server will reject it.

What you can do:

1. generate a new CSR
2. instruct CA to ignore subject field and specify another one during certificate issuance (this procedure depends on CA software).

Comment: cant we use same private key ?

Comment: Why not? You can reuse existing key.

Comment: Hi , forgot comment back. I have searched and found one way. Thank you for responding back :)

Comment: @Ten-Coin  What is the way you found?  It is a tool that extracts the info from the .csr, lets you edit it, when resigns it?

Comment: @PawelVeselov wouldn't you mind to explain what `signature` means in PKCS#10 structure then: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2986#section-4.2 ?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

Try this:

```
openssl req -in /your/csr/file.csr -out /your/csr/newfile.csr -subj "/C=ID/ST=REDACTED/L=REDACTED/O=REDACTED/OU=REDACTED/CN=newsubdomain.example.com"
```

**More descriptive way:**

If you describe the CSR with openssl command `openssl req -in /your/csr/file.csr -noout -text` you will see there are some sections in it:

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 0 (0x0)
        Subject: C=ID, ST=REDACTED, L=REDACTED, O=REDACTED, OU=REDACTED, CN=subdomain.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:00:11:
```

To get the current `Subject` part of your CSR, you can run this command: `openssl req -in /your/csr/file.csr -noout -subject`, and you will get this:

```
subject=/C=ID/ST=REDACTED/L=REDACTED/O=REDACTED/OU=REDACTED/CN=subdomain.example.com
```

You can change it to match your need by running this command:

```
openssl req -in /your/csr/file.csr -out /your/csr/newfile.csr -subj "/C=ID/ST=REDACTED/L=REDACTED/O=REDACTED/OU=REDACTED/CN=newsubdomain.example.com"
```

Then voila! your have a new CSR with the same public key (the `Subject Public Key Info` section) with updated `Subject` part. You can always inspect your CSR again with the same command as above, but remember to specify the correct file (i.e. `/your/csr/newfile.csr`).

Comment: I could generate the new CSR , however is not valid , there is a decode error (signature invalid), Do i need to create a new one from scratch?